# X11 XClientMessageEvent union porting to 64-bit... Bug?

Tags: x11, xorg

I'm working with a legacy application on Linux that uses ClientMessage to do messaging between cooperating processes. The XClientMessageEvent structure provides a union as a convenience to use for custom data:

```
union {
    char b[20];
    short s[10];
    long l[5];
} data;
```

And the man page claims: **"The b, s, and l members represent data of twenty 8-bit values, ten 16-bit values, and five 32-bit values. "**

This is all well and good if compiling on a 32-bit system. Just different access to the 20 bytes of the union, right? Well, on a 64-bit system, the "long l[5]" member takes up 40 bytes.

My testing shows that if the sender considers these as 64-bit longs and uses them, the receiver only gets the first 20 bytes of the "data" structure. The last 20 bytes are lost (appear as zeros to the receiver).

Since the application relies pretty heavily on packing this union with both shorts and longs, I'm stuck.

I'm using: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-22.el6.centos.x86_64

Has anyone had any experience in solving this? Am I just not understanding this correctly?

It sure seems like a bug in X to me. 64-bit X11 has been around for a long time. I've only seen one other mention of this issue on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a XClientMessage on 64 bit, this works great to go fullscreen:

```
XClientMessageEvent xevent;
memset (&xevent, 0, sizeof (xevent));

xevent.type = ClientMessage;
xevent.window = mw;
xevent.message_type = XInternAtom (m_display, "_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS", False);
xevent.format = 32;
xevent.data.l[0] = m_fullScreen;
xevent.data.l[1] = m_fullScreen;
xevent.data.l[2] = m_fullScreen;
xevent.data.l[3] = m_fullScreen;
xevent.data.l[4] = 1; // source indication
XSendEvent (m_display, DefaultRootWindow (m_display), False, SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask, (XEvent *) & xevent);
```

Did you set `xevent.format` as well? It's not documented but I guess it's used to hint as to which of the 3 members b, s or l are used.

Comment: Yes, I've set xevent.format. It is documented as indicating how the "data" block is to be considered for byte-swapping purposes. I've tried 16 and 32 and neither work as I expected. If I did what you did above, the "receiver" would see xevent.data.l[4] as "0" instead of "1".